# Visual Studio line deletion

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2003

Is there any way in Visual Studio 2003 that I can delete a line without it being copied into the clipboard?

There are instances when I want to copy the first line of a block of text and then delete the following *n* lines but this then puts the last line I deleted into the clipboard, which is very annoying. I have come from a brief keymap background and I could easily do this with Alt-D.

<sub>And while I'm on the subject, why on earth have MS stopped supporting the brief keymap?</sub>

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> deletes without storing in the clipboard.

Or go to: tools/options/keyboard and look up the command called "Edit.LineDelete" if you want to change the shortcut to something easier.

Comment: Thanks for the reply CTRL-SHIFT-L does indeed work, is there anywhere that details all this kind of info, or do you have to wade through all the possible key commands looking for one that sounds like it does what you want?

Comment: I found it by going to the keyboard shortcut options and searching for the word delete then looking at all the matches. There are keyboard shortcut cheat sheets around (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E5F902A8-5BB5-4CC6-907E-472809749973&displaylang=en for example) but they don't contain all the shortcuts - including this one.

Comment: oh my god this was driving me insane I thought my visual studio was bugging out. thank you so much for this!!